# how to use window.open with f:ajax and listener

Tags: ajax, jquery, jsf, jsf-2

As per the existing behaviour, on click of command button, controller is redirected to different page with processed results. Instead of redirecting to a different page, I would like all the result to be opened in a pop up window.

Below is the existing code in Facelets file.

```
<h:commandLink id="pp" styleClass="submitbutton" onclick="return isChecked();">
<h:outputText value="My Report" style="color: white;"/>
<f:param name="IdNumber" value="#{IdNumber}"/>
<f:ajax render="allOtherPages" listener="#{someController.showAllDetails}" execute="@form" onevent="showProgressBar()"/> 
</h:commandLink>
```

Below is code in controller

```
public void showAllDetails(AjaxBehaviorEvent event){
HttpServletRequest request = getHttpRequest();
request.setAttribute("IdNumber", request.getParameter("IdNumber"));
somePageController.setContentPage("new.xhtml");
}
```

How can I change the code to achieve the above or share some link with similar example?

Comment: Why don't you go for primefaces dialog box, you can easily open it from your java end.

Comment: I am not aware about the primefaces dialog box. I want to use the existing code as much as possible.